# Save the username of the loggedin user in the database instead of the userid

Tags: python, django, postgresql, postgis

I would like to save the username of the loggedin user in the database.
But only the userid shows up in the databse, and i can't seem to work out how to change it to the username.

Can you help me get this ?

Thanks

Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models as db_models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class Fertidb(models.Model):
    user = db_models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    culture = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    area = models.IntegerField()
    plot = models.FileField(upload_to='KML_FILES', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f' Parcelles de {self.user.username}'
```

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Fertidb


class FertidbForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Fertidb
        labels = {
            "plot": "Importez votre fichier KML"
        }
        fields = ['culture', 'area', 'plot']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import FertidbForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

title = 'FERTISAT'


@login_required
def fertisatmap(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        o_form = FertidbForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if o_form.is_valid():
        fertidb = o_form.save(commit=False)
        fertidb.user = request.user  # o_form.user = request.user.username()
        fertidb.save()
        messages.success(request, f'Vos informations ont été envoyées')
        return redirect('fertisat-map')
    else:
        o_form = FertidbForm()
    context = {'title': title, 'o_form': o_form}
    return render(request, 'fertisat/fertisatmap.html ', context)
```

Comment: Where is `fertidb` defined in your `views.py`?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I was making changes and copied the wrong code; Its corrected

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue but it's perfectly normal to have only the user `id` in your `Fertidb` table: it's a foreign key. It means that it refers to the user with this `id` in the `User` table. You have the username in this table.

Comment: Thanks @frankie567, how do I do to get the username in the fertidb table ?

Comment: But why would you want to do this? You don't have to. It's the whole point of [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) ; which, among others things, roughly mean that you shouldn't repeat the same data on several tables. Luckily, Django handles foreign key very easily. If you want to get the username, you can just do `fertidb.user.username` (we say that we "traverse" the relationship).

Comment: Thanks Frankie, i would like to do it so it save me the hassle of crosschecking databases when i want to exctrat them.  So what  you say is I add in views the following ? fertidb = o_form.save(commit=False)
            fertidb.user.username = request.user.username                                                      So i did it but i got an error RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /fertisatmap/
Fertidb has no user.

Comment: Well, if you **really** want to do it (which I DON'T recommend), you have to add another `CharField` in your `Fertidb` model called `username`. Then you can do `fertidb.username = request.user.username`. But again, I don't understand why you want to do that. `JOIN` queries are very easy to do in SQL.

Comment: Thanks @ Frankie567, you have conviced me. I will join databases later and follow best practices

Comment: @Benda Glad to hear it! Actually you are joining *tables* not *databases*. You have one *database* with several *tables* (in your case one table for `Fertidb`, another for `User`). I would recommend you read about SQL databases before using an abstract tool like Django ORM.

Answer (score 1):

You DO NOT want to store the username in your `Fertidb̀ model. Well, to be more exact, you DEFINITLY DO NOT want to store the username *instead* of the user id, and the chances you really want to store the username *in addition* of the user id are rather low.

Explication: `User.username` is an editable field, so it's not a viable primary key. If you try use it as ForeignKey, your data will get corrupted as soon as the user edits their username. OTHO, `User.id` IS a proper stable primary key, so that's what you want as foreign key. From then, you can get the username quite easily (with `self.user.username`), AND you will always get the up-to-date value.

The only reason you'd want to duplicate the username in your model would be to keep the user's username value *at the moment the fertidb record was created*. This kind of denormalization makes sense in some contexts - for example in a ecommerce app to store a product's price at the moment the user orders it (so the order's detail and total don't change when you later change your product's price...), but I fail to see how you would have such a need for a username (not that there's no valid use case here - just none I can think of xD).

IOW: keep your foreignky on User.id - that IS the RightThing(tm) -, and *if you have a valid reason / requirement for duplicating the username*, then do it in a distinct field.

Also, given your question, I kindly suggest that you stop writing code for a few days, learn about proper relational database modeling, and how this translates in Django ORM. Well, proper relational database modeling takes more than a few days to learn actually but at least you need to get the basics right.

Answer (score -2):

Register the new model if you didnt yet in admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Fertidb

admin.site.register(Fertidb)
```

Then run python manage.py makemigrations and then python manage.py migrate.

Comment: I have done it,n thank you. The code works, but i don't know how to get the username in fertidb table instead of userid ?

Comment: {{ user.username|default:user.id }}

Comment: where do I add this ?

Comment: Thats how you call the table to extract the username , the username is already in models for User so I dont see a reason why you should create another field for username in model fertidb when you can just call it like this.